# updating php extensions Ubuntu

Tags: php, ubuntu, inotify

I have a problem with updating the pecl inotify extension.
but i think it applys to all extensions.

i recently updated my server.
first i got the error that inotify.so wasn't found.
so i copied it to the new php extension directory

```
@server:~# locate inotify.so
/usr/lib/php5/20100525/inotify.so
/usr/lib/php5/20121212/inotify.so
```

but now i'm getting the error:

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: inotify: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20100525
PHP    compiled with module API=20121212
These options need to match
```

so how do i update / reinstall / reconfigure these extensions?

Comment: The `.so` file you copied is not made for that specific version of PHP.

Comment: But the other one you found apparently is; copy that into place instead.

Comment: "the other one" is the one i've copied. so they both are build 20100525.
how do i make one specific for this php version?

Answer (score 2):

the "long" way round.

```
pecl uninstall inotify

pecl install inotify
```

there should be a better way to reconfigure an php extension. right?!
but this works for now!